# Can't disable quartz-scheduler logging using SLF4J

Tags: java, maven, logging, quartz-scheduler, slf4j

After adding quartz-scheduler to a project, Tomcat's server log is being spammed with the following message:

> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 12:15:06.319
>   [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG
>   o.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 0 triggers

I'm trying to disable that log message, which repeats every 25-seconds or so.  I've been through a number of other answers to this same question, such as:

- [Disable quartz logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421353/disable-quartz-logging)
- [stop quartz debug logging log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091536/stop-quartz-debug-logging-log4j)
- [Disabling Log4J Output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571960/disabling-log4j-output-in-java)

...and none of the approaches suggested are working.

I have the following dependencies declared in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I've added the following `log4j.properties` settings to my project:

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
log4j.logger.quartz=OFF
log4j.logger.o.quartz=OFF
log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF
```

...and also the following `simplelogger.properties`:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=error
```

In addition to attempting the programmatic solution suggested on one of the linked answers, which should disable all logging and goes roughly like:

```
List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger>list(LogManager.getCurrentLoggers());
loggers.add(LogManager.getRootLogger());
for ( Logger logger : loggers ) {
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
}
```

That seems to disable everything *except* the log message from quartz when it runs.

Is there a way to get rid of the log message from quartz, short of modifying the quartz source-code to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logging entry above doesn't look like Log4J. I think thats ACL or JUL. When you are using Slf4j to Log4J, you also need to [redirect these frameworks to Slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html). Add these dependencies to your project as well:

```
<!--Redirect Apache Commons Logging to Slf4J -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<!--Redirect Java Util Logging to Slf4J -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Read [this doc page](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) about redirecting Jul to Slf4J, too. Be sure to exclude any existing commons-logging.jar files from your project, through Maven.

[image]

(From the [Slf4J documentation page](http://www.slf4j.org/images/legacy.png))

And if all else fails, try the following code:

```
//see if we can find the offending logger through slf4j's LoggerFactory
org.slf4j.Logger logger = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(Class.forName("org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread"));
if (logger != null && logger instanceof ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) {
    //the slf4j Logger interface doesn't expose any configuration API's, but 
    //we can cast to a class that does; so cast it and disable the logger
    ((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)logger).setLevel(
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.OFF);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It didn't quite work on its own, but I was able to add a bit of code after making this change to finally silence the quartz logger.